# PHP method of function for remove child dirs on array

Tags: php, algorithm

I create a function for remove child dirs on arrays structure. USer for error or mistake, has put on scenario, subdirs child of a parent dir already in config list.

```
/dir_a/subdir_a
/dir_b/subdir_a/subdir_a
/dir_b/subdir_a/subdir_b
/dir_b/
/dir_c/subdir_a/
...
```

Code

```
$local_pre_order = array_unique($local_sync);
asort($local_pre_order);
$local_order = array();
foreach ($local_pre_order as $value)
{
    $repeat = false;
    foreach ($local_pre_order as $value2)
    {
       $pos = strpos($value,$value2);
       if (($pos !== false ) && ($value != $value2) && ($pos == 0)) {
          $repeat = true;
          break;
       }
    }
    if (!$repeat) {
       $local_order[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Sort OK

```
/dir_a/subdir_a
/dir_b/
/dir_c/subdir_a/
```

I think it's a no good programing. Work but not fine. IMHO. Any ideas for best code?

Comment: Have u tried using .htacess file? (In case u use Apache?)

Comment: It's no't question about apache. It's one array (get info of two files). Content of arry can has dirs duplicates or subdir form a another dir on array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is the way to go. Note that when sorted, all the child subdirs will be immediatelly after their parents. So it's just a matter of avoiding adding subdirs if the last added dir has a common prefix with it.

PHP isn't my first language, so please don't mind this non-idiomatic code.

```
$local_sync = [
    "/dir_a/subdir_a",
    "/dir_b/subdir_a/subdir_a",
    "/dir_b/subdir_a/subdir_b",
    "/dir_b/",
    "/dir_c/subdir_a/"
];

$copy = $local_sync;
asort($copy);
$output = array();

foreach ($copy as $value)
    if (strpos($value, end($output)) !== 0) 
       $output[] = $value;

print_r($output)
```

Comment: A lot of thanks. Your code it's pretty, and I learn with it correct use of end and argument passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to rely on the array's structure, don't rely on the array being sorted or a comparison between the current path and the previous. What you want to do is use `dirname ()` to get each path's directory name, and search the output array for each path, only adding the path to the output array if it's not already in the output array.

Like so...

```
$directory_paths = array (
    '/dir_a/subdir_a',
    '/dir_b/subdir_a/subdir_a',
    '/dir_b/subdir_a/subdir_b',
    '/dir_b/',
    '/dir_c/subdir_a/'
);

$sorted_paths = $directory_paths;
asort ($sorted_paths);
$output = array ();

foreach ($sorted_paths as $key => $path) {
    $directory = $path;
    $levels = substr_count (trim ($path, '/'), '/') - 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++) {
        $directory = dirname ($directory);
    }

    if (in_array ($directory, $sorted_paths)) {
        $output[$key] = $path;
    }
}

ksort ($output);
$output = array_values ($output);

echo print_r ($output, true);
```

Comment: For `$directory_paths = array (
    '/dir_b/subdir_a/subdir_a',
    '/dir_b/subdir_a/subdir_b',
    '/dir_a/subdir_a',
    '/dir_b/',
    '/dir_c/subdir_a/'
);` your algorithm returns wrong results.

Comment: `/dir_a/subdir_a` is technically a sub-directory so it's parent is included instead. The thing about algorithm's is, they have to have some kind of logic, "remove all sub-directories" is the logic of the algorithm above. Adding a limit of how many sub-directories are allowed would give you the behavior you're after, so I've edited the code to do that.

Comment: You are including a directory that wasn't included in the original array. I'm pretty sure that this isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: @JuanLopes Fair enough. I've changed the code to do that.